How to use vue-chartjs with unplugin-vue-components?
I try to use unplugin-vue-components to automatically import Vue components from vue-chartjs, but I don't know how.
I found this in unplugin-vue-components documentation:

You can also write your own resolver quickly:
Components({
  resolvers: [
    // example of importing Vant
    (componentName) => {
      // where `componentName` is always CapitalCase
      if (componentName.startsWith('Van'))
        return { name: componentName.slice(3), from: 'vant' }
    },
  ],
})


But since components from vue-chartjs don't come with a common prefix, like CBar or ChartBar, I have no idea how to config unplugin-vue-components.

The following will import all charts from vue-chartjs and prefix them with "C":
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
const charts = [
  'Bar',
  'Bubble',
  'Doughnut',
  'Line',
  'Pie',
  'PolarArea',
  'Radar',
  'Scatter'
]

Components({
  resolvers: [
    (name) => {
      if (charts.includes(name)) {
        return { name: `C${name}`, from: 'vue-chartjs' }
      }
    }
  ]
})


CBar, CBubble, CDoughnut etc... are now available without importing them.
Feel free to remove the charts you don't use from the names array.

Note: you don't need a common prefix in order to auto-import components using unplugin. If you change the return line to:
   return { name, from: 'vue-chartjs' }

in the above example, the charts will be auto-imported with their original names.

I make wrong examples. The components I got is like Bar, Pie and so on. The components I wish to have is like CBar, CPie, in this way I could use C as common prefix.

That wasn't clear from your initial request. Updated the answer accordingly. However, I don't understand why you want the "C" prefix instead of using their actual names!?

I don't know I can just write a list and import. I thought only with common prefix can the components be auto-imported by unplugging :(
